# Unable to host/connect to gRPC server using host name

Tags: c#, windows, console, grpc, .net-6.0

I am having trouble connecting to my gRPC service. I've implemented some server and client functionality and tested it in debug mode, running both server and client application in the same VS environment and it works just fine. However, when I run the server (as a console application) and try to connect to it using IP or host name on the same box, I can't make the connection.

I created a barebones out of shelf "ASP.Net Core gRPC Service" Greeter .NET 6 application and added a basic console application to the solution to isolate this issue.
I've made no changes to the server/service part. Set GrpcServices="Both" in the protobuffers. Client's side points to the server's protobuffer:

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <Protobuf Include="..\GRPC-Server\Protos\greet.proto" GrpcServices="Both" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

The client implementation is pretty basic:

```
var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001"); 
var greeterClient = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);

HelloRequest request = new HelloRequest()
{
    Name = "Stranger"
};

HelloReply response = greeterClient.SayHello(request);

Console.WriteLine(response.Message);

Console.ReadLine();
```

This works fine when I configure both projects to start.

Then I built the server part (console app) and started it separately in CMD app.
Now, if I run the client in VS on the same laptop, it works fine again, but if I try change the address to use my laptop name in the client:

```
var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://MYHOSTNAME:5001");
```

I am getting exception on the client:
"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

I tired to use the local IP address in the client like this:

```
var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://127.0.0.1:5001");
```

and got exception:
"The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch"

So I tried to handle it with  HttpClientHandler:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
    HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;

var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://127.0.0.1:5001",
    new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpHandler = handler });
```

and it worked fine.

However, when I try to use the same approach with the box name, it fails again:
"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

Some other things I tried are:

- Created firewall exceptions to allow inbound and outbound connections
  for ports 5000-5001.
- Tried to telnet to port 5001 and it connects fine for localhost and
  127.0.0.1, but for MYHOSTNAME it says: Could not open connection to the host, on port 5001: Connect failed.
- Just to double check, ran this test on a different test box by
  copying the server app and opening ports, with the same result.

I think I can try using certificates, but it may take me some time to implement and since I've never did it before it is easy to introduce another issue, whereas the primary issue may be an issue in the certificate scenario as well.

One other thing I tried in VS is I set applicationUrl in launchSettings.json to https://192.168.1.200:5001 and in the client:

```
var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://MYHOSTNAME:5001", new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpHandler = handler });
```

and it worked fine. However, when I change the IP address to the name in launchSettings.json, it starts listening to https://[::]:5001 and connection fails. I am not sure if I can expect having static IP on the hosting system. One other issue here is I was able to set host/port for the server in VS environment, but I am not sure how to do it in Release build. I added production profile to launchSettings.json, but it does not seem to have any effect on the build. Otherwise I do not see a good config file in this console build where such changes can apply: GRPC-Server.deps.json, GRPC-Server.runtimeconfig.json, appsettings.json.

Comment: HTTP uses TCP for transport layer.  The source and destination IP has to be different.  So the server uses the loopback 127.0.0.1 and the client uses the IP address of the machine.  So after you made the correction failed the TLS encryption because of certificate issues.

Comment: Shouldn't I still be able to telnet MYHOSTNAME 5001 from the same box?

Comment: Telnet is TCP protocol while your code is HTTPS.  HTTP uses TCP as transport layer.  HTTP is an application layer where you need matching opening and closing tags.  Using Telnet TCP) won't work because HTTPS expects TLS to occur before any HTTP Request is processed.  The server will reject any connections unless the TLS completes.